# Reading a file as a ByteArray?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, memory, binary

I want to read in large files as byte strings.

`Import[..., "Byte"]` yields a list of Integers that takes up much more space (16 times more) than the file.

`ByteArray` would be the proper way to store such sequences in memory, but how can I read a file into a `ByteArray` directly?

I know I can later apply `ByteArray` to the result of `Import`, but I would prefer to not use so much memory intermittently.

Importing as `Integer64` uses much less extra memory, but it's not an option because it does not read in everything when the size is not divisible by 4.

Importing as `"String"` seems to not use much more memory than the file, but I am not sure whether this might lead to problems since I have arbitrary byte sequences. I'm also not sure how I would index the n-th byte (rather than the n-th multibyte character).
String does store multibyte variable length characters (utf-8 style), right? It's not just a wchar_t/short/int array, is it?

Any ideas?

Comment: To begin answering this would require knowing what your file looks like, i.e., how the data is stored in the file.

Comment: I don't think multibyte encodings are relevant to your main question, but to answer it: as far as I know, in v11 strings still can't handle characters that can handle UTF16 surrogate pairs. That's because Mathematica got unicode support before the unicode spec was finalized, and got stuck with a 16-bit representation (i.e. can only handle the basic multilingual plane).  This should not concern you because when importing as `"String"`, only 8-bit "characters" are returned (i.e. characters represent bytes)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @bills I'm interested in the raw bytes in the file, I don't need to know the structure for now.

Comment: Related: [(a/151073)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151073/280).

Comment: Strongly related WC discussion: "[What is the intended purpose of ByteArray & how can we use/convert it?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1053802)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Import[..., "String"]` and `Export[..., "String"]` are meant precisely for this and will not cause problems.  This is guaranteed to give you "character codes" between 0..255, and the string can represent the file contents exactly.

This differs significantly from `Import[..., "Text"]` which will handle character encodings, line endings, etc. and is meant for text, not for arbitrary binary data.

---

I have not used `ByteArray` and I am not sure about its purpose, but I got the impression that it is meant for the cryptography functionality as I couldn't find any other high-level functions that work with it.  It does work with basic list manipulation functions though.

> I know I can later apply ByteArray to the result of Import, but I would prefer to not use so much memory intermittently.

How about reading in chunks, and packing each chunk into a `ByteArray`, to avoid high memory usage?

```
chunkSize = 300*1024; (* 300 kB due to the size of my test file *)

stream = OpenRead["file.pdf", BinaryFormat -> True];

ba = Join @@ First@Last@Reap@While[True,
      res = BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", chunkSize];
      If[res === {}, Break[]]; (* there was no more data to read *)
      Sow[ByteArray[res]]
     ]

Close[stream]
```

Comment: I'm curious to know more specifically what you mean when you say `ByteArray` "doesn't integrate well with the rest of the system". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @dionys It was unfair of me to say that, so I corrected it.

Comment: Thank you. Another "high-level function" supporting `ByteArray` is `URLRead` with element `"BodyByteArray"`.

Comment: @masterxilo Thanks, it's exactly the kind of function I was looking for but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new in M11.3 function [`ReadByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadByteArray):

```
path = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}, "FilePath"];
MaxMemoryUsed[ba = ReadByteArray[path]] //AbsoluteTiming
Head[ba]
```

> {0.000439, 723768}
>
> ByteArray

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using new in version 11.2 `StringToByteArray` you can reduce the memory requirements:

```
file = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}, "FilePath"];

byteList = BinaryReadList[path];
string = Import[path, "String"];
byteList // ByteCount
string // ByteCount
byteArray = StringToByteArray[string]; // MaxMemoryUsed
byteArray
```

> ```
> 5024024
>
> 945208
>
> 945504
> ```
>
> [image: ByteArrray]

As one can see from the above, `String` requires 5 times lesser memory than packed array of integers returned by `BinaryReadList` while `StringToByteArray` (without second argument) takes only a tiny amount of additional memory.

A more memory efficient representation of the data can be obtained by specifying `"ISO8859-1"` encoding by the cost of increasing intermediate memory requirements:

```
byteArray2 = StringToByteArray[string, "ISO8859-1"]; // MaxMemoryUsed
byteArray2
```

> ```
> 1573240
> ```
>
> [image: ByteArray]

Hence it would be useful to have an option to import a file as `ByteArrray` directly.

---

> String does store multibyte variable length characters (utf-8 style), right? It's not just a wchar_t/short/int array, is it?

[Citing Itai Seggev](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1057042):

> We internally encode strings in a variant of UTF-8. Now, of course, any byte can be faithfully converted to/from ISO8859-1, but that encoding only equals UTF-8 for the lower 7 bits. For other values, you need to use multiple bytes per character. So using a string to store byte data is both less space efficient and time efficient (since you need to ensure to correct conversion between the two encodings.)